# MOSFET Vds is too high when MOSFET turn on

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

Few days ago, I upload question about MOSFET driver getting too hot.

That problem was solved by your help. thank you.

But I have another problem. I connect 80ohm load to MOSFET like this figure.

[image]

PSPICE simulation told me Vds is 4.98mV.
But I measure real circuit, Vds up to 12V. It cause some little heat.

Is this happen cause by gate resistor R2 ?
or MOSFET broken? I don't know what to do..

Comment: What voltage do you measure on the FET Gate when connected to +12V via R2, and when R2 is connected to ground instead of +12V?

Comment: Measure V2, and the voltage across R2. If V2 < 10V, replace it, If V(R2) > 0 (at DC), Q1 has suffered ESD so replace Q1. If neither of these is the case, explain further.

Comment: @user_1818839 you mean voltage which engage to R2?
I will supply 12V without pwm. thank you

Comment: If you were modulating V2 with PWM, then R2 and the huge gate capacitances in Q1 form a low pass filter keeping the gate voltage at precisely the wrong value for efficient switching and cool running. That info should have been in the question. You want Q1 gate to be either 0 (off) or >10V (on) and switch from one to the other as fast as possible. Which takes AMPS (for nanoseconds) and is often done by a purpose built gate driver IC.

Answer (score 2):

You should connect a pull-down resistor to your gate, otherwise the gate remains floating. The gate is a capacitor like, so applying a battery voltage you do charge it, but if you disconnect the battery, the gate remains charged. You have to discharge it in order to make the MOSFET open.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiozr7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Finally I figure out why IRFZ44N take 12V. Because actually thats not IRFZ44N. That is TIP31C NPN BJT... I'm sorry upload question without checking parts on circuit.